# Passing JavaScript/JQuery value to PHP WITH page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know the ways to do this is are:

- redirect to a PHP script
- make an AJAX call to a PHP script

I actually want the results in another page so AJAX is not needed (newbie here so trying to keep it simple).

What I want to do is:

1. user input in html
2. javascript/jQuery calculates it to variables
3. variables are passed to the database, filters and supplies the data (results) to be inserted into the next page

1 is already working. For step 2 and 3 so far I've got

```
<script>
  function JavascriptFunction() { 
    let variable1, variable2, variable3;
    let variable1 = 'a', variable2 = 'b', variable3 = 'c';
    let variables = variable1, variable2, variable3;

    window.location.href = "nextpage.php?variables=" + variables; 
  }
</script>

<?php
  $select = mysql_query("select * from tabl1 where variables = '".$_GET['variables']."'"); 
  echo $select;
?>

*returned values gets inserted in html content*
```

I do not want to store those variables in the URL. Is there a correct way to do this differently? I thought of storing them in a hidden HTML value and letting PHP get the values from there.

I would love your input on best practices for this. If I should do this completely different please also do let me know

Comment: Put the calculated values in to hidden fields in a form which the user submits with a button, or better still just send the user-entered value *only* and do the calculation on th server side. This is more secure - especially if the calculation is business logic-sensitive

Comment: you can encrypt data and pass if you dont want to show to user.

Comment: ya just submit by post to other page the values

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not sure if I can let the server calculate it. While the user is inserting data (by selecting buttons), the buttons change and values are calculated according to the buttons. So the buttons are dynamic and the buttons shown depends on what the user chooses.

Comment: Fair enough then. Sending the data via a POSTed form would work for you, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so, method=POST, after the calculations with .js, insert those calculations in the HTML (hidden) with .js and in the next page get those value with php ($_POST['values'];?

Comment: I would do the calculations as the user updates the field, and set them in the hidden fields ready to be sent when the use clicks submit

Comment: The user interface part are a couple of buttons instead of a actual form where they can input whatever they want. Will that also work in this case?